# Haskell new line character

Tags: haskell

I need to compare Windows new line character ('\r\n') but I get

```
lexical error in string/character literal at character '\\'

['\r\n']
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify on the great answers you received so far: `\r\n` isn't a newline character - particularly, it's not a character. It's two characters; so you need a String literal (as mentioned). Of course, this problem you're having has nothing to do with Haskell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `'\r\n'` is not a valid character. This should not be surprising since Windows uses **two** characters to signify the end of a line. This means that you need a `String`:

```
"\r\n"
```

This also means that you will need more complex analysis when parsing input. Looking for a sequence of two characters is a little more difficult than looking for a single character.

One solution is to remove all `'\r'` characters with a simple filter applied to every `String` that might contain `"\r\n"`:

```
deMicrosoftifyString = filter (/= '\r')
```

Comment: @CosminMihai Just saying, you'd have this problem in any language, it is in no way unique to Haskell and its types/libraries.  You can blame Microsoft for deciding that two characters are better than one, even though there is no real need for the carriage return character whatsoever.

Answer (score 9):

Note that for files/streams in the default text mode on Windows, `"\r\n"` is automatically converted to `"\n"` on input, and vice versa on output.

If you have special needs that the default doesn't handle, you may wish to look into the [`System.IO.hSetNewlineMode`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/System-IO.html#g:25) function, which allows you to set the newline conversion used for a specific handle. For example:

```
hSetNewlineMode handle universalNewlineMode
```

sets a handle to accept either `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` as newline (internally `"\n"`) on input, but uses the native OS convention on output.

Comment: +1 Definitely better than my answer because you give Haskell-specific ways to deal with this issue.

Comment: Indeed, the conversion between `\n` and `\r\n` is even performed by C on files opened in text mode in Windows. It is a part of the C standard which ensures that you can write portable C, and many languages -- including Haskell -- copied that feature.